# How to Mock ApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, javabeans

I am trying to test a POST request, which should send me a pdf file back.
In the POST request is a bean generated with BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils with the method qualifiedBeanOfType.
The Parameters:

- BeanFactory beanFactory is AutowireCapableBeanFactory. This is mocked
  with @MockBean
- Class beanType is internal Interface
- String qualifier is 'application/pdf'

Problem:
When I try to test this POST request and I execute the command:

`BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(beanFactory, beanType, qualifier);`

The Exception is thrown:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'application/pdf' available: No matching ProfileReportGenerator bean found for bean name 'application/pdf'! (Note: Qualifier matching not supported because given BeanFactory does not implement ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.)`

I know that the problem is how the beanFactory-bean will be instantiated. But I am not able to solve it.

Test Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

}
```

With best regards,
Luis

Comment: Should there be a bean named `application/pdf`? With Spring Boot, you use `@SpringBootTest` + `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` instead of the two annotations that you are using.

Comment: ```application/pdf``` is rather a Content-Type header and not a bean qualifier

Comment: @Tobb 
Should there be a bean named application/pdf? no, this is the Content-Type . But it is used for the creation of the bean, that will be used for the creation of the pdf file. Do you need more information?

I will try your second option as well

Comment: @alainlompo exactly, it is used to create a bean, which will be used for the pdf creation. Do you need more information?

Comment: Yes, can you share the corresponding configuration?

Comment: @alainlompo did you meant the application.properties?
- There is only the connection to the MongoDB and the server.port

Comment: No, but the qualifier seems wrong to me.Is it so reflected in the beans definition? See for example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

Comment: Your error message states that there is no bean named `application/pdf`. So if there is not supposed to be one with that name, then there is an error in the code that tries to retrieve the bean. What you are sending as qualifier is the name of the bean to be retrieved.